# How to support HTTPS with TXT record?

Tags: domain-name-system, txt-record

I would lik to redirect all link from `wiki.negativity.fr` to the github wiki.

Actually, I'm doing this:

```
wiki IN TXT "1|https://github.com/Elikill58/Negativity/wiki"
```

And it works, but only when using HTTP.

How can I make it works with HTTPS ? Like `https://wiki.negativity.fr` works fine.

I'm using OVH DNS, and default one where using "1|url" or "3|text" but I didn't find documentation about id 1 & 3. Maybe they can cause the problem.

Comment: That record has nothing to do with the redirect. `curl -I wiki.negativity.fr` shows an OVH server issuing a 302 redirect.

Comment: You can not do an redirect with an TXT-Record. For an HTTP(S) Redirect you need a webserver (or your provider), which delivers the correct answer for your domain. I am not a OVH customer, so I can not test it by myself. Read the page [Redirecting a Domain Name](https://docs.ovh.com/us/en/domains/redirect-domain-name/) from OVH Docs.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's just an OVH feature which is not related to DNS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is custom functionality, that is not strictly done in DNS (alone). You may find that not only OVH but also other providers will
support setting up services, like redirects for web sites and e-mail forwarding from their DNS control panel, as that is a convenient User Interface.

In reality and behind the screens DNS is not the (only) actual technology involved.

In this case, OVH runs a web server, which is where the `A` record for your DNS record `wiki.negativity.fr` points to.
On that web server probably runs a trivial web service, that will evaluate the incoming request; if a correctly formatted TXT record exists for the host name component in the requested URL it generates HTTP redirect to the location found in that TXT DNS record.

The reason it fails with https : there is no SSL support set up  on the server offering the redirect service. And if it were, there probably wouldn't be a valid certificate for your specific domain and you'd get a browser error/warning.   I can imagine that the overhead for setting up certificates for all domains that want a redirect would be too much for a free redirect service.

Comment: I have checked `wiki.negativity.fr` port 443 and it looks that the redirect server simply does not listen on port 443 at all.
If it were an invalid certificate issue, the OP could probably manually accept the certificate exception in his browser and the the redirect would work. But the redirect server just doesn't support HTTPS.

Comment: edited to clarify that.