# Bind9 - Forward specific record to another name server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I have a master zone (example.com) and several A records that belong to that zone (server1.example.com, server2.example.com, etc.). Those records resolve to internally hosted servers. I want to resolve another record (server3.example.com) to an external name server (cloudflare or google). I found a lot of examples of how to do this for sub domains or how to create overrides for certain external domains, but had trouble finding an example of this particular situation.

To give more context, the only reason I am looking to do this is to redirect the server3.example.com domain to a specific URL.

I know that Bind9 cannot do this, but my public name server can do this very easily. My public name server is providing this redirect correctly, but this does not work for my internal clients.

I'm currently using an internal apache server to create the redirect, but I'd like to simplify this and eliminate apache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For starters, DNS can't redirect to an HTTP URL, that always requires a web server.

DNS servers only serve DNS records.

Other vendors may use their DNS control panel to allow their customers to have a simple interface to set pseudo DNS records to manage email aliases and/or HTTP redirects, but that means that those vendors still run an email server or web server that implements the SMTP respectively the HTTP protocol to effect the email forwarding or a web browser redirect.

**Note:** Typically such a redirect service won't redirect HTTPS  web requests which might be a problem when you for example use HSTS.

See also my explanation here: [How to support HTTPS with TXT record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1108439/how-to-support-https-with-txt-record/1108476#1108476)  (the title of the Q&A already hints at the confusion)

---

I would expect that the redirect service at your DNS provider will only look in their own DNS servers. So you will need to first ensure that a DNS zone for either your domain `example.com` or preferably for the `server3.example.com` subdomain exists to allow you to make the special purpose pseudo DNS record for the redirect.

I'm not sure if I read your question correctly and if this  is already the case or not.

---

Then in your actual/internal authoritative DNS you can create a record to points either directly to the IP-address of the redirect server used by that provider:

```
server3.example.com.  IN A 192.168.1.2
```

Or alternatively (to answer your literal question)
DNS has three methods to *"redirect / forward"* DNS records:

- **[`CNAME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)**  Alias of one name to another: the DNS lookup will continue by retrying the lookup with the new name.

  ```
    server3.example.com. IN CNAME redirects.provider.example.net.
  ```
- **[`DNAME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNAME_record)** Alias for a name and all its subnames, unlike CNAME, which is an alias for only the exact name. Like a CNAME record, the DNS lookup will continue by retrying the lookup with the new name.

  ```
  server3.example.com. IN DNAME redirects.provider.example.net.
  ```
- **[`NS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server#Authoritative_name_server)** Delegates a DNS zone to use the given authoritative name servers.

  ```
  server3.example.com. IN NS ns1.provider.example.net.
  server3.example.com. IN NS ns2.provider.example.net.
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @HBrujin is accurate but perhaps not as illuminating and complete as it could be.

> but had trouble finding an example of this particular situation.

....because DNS is NOT designed to work in this way. It is impossible for server3.example.com to be handled by a different DNS server than *.example.com.

> (cloudflare or google)

If you know the name which cloudflare or google use to describe the location of the service, then you should add a CNAME record to the example.com zone, e.g.

```
server3.example.com CNAME host1234.cloudflare.net
```

Now when you type `https://server3.example.com` into your browser, it will find the CNAME record, then lookup the next record in the chain (and keep repeating) until it finds an IP address (A or AAA). But when it tries to open a connection to the end point it finds, it will first send an SNI request for "server3.example.com" and the subsequent HTTP request will contain the header "Host: server3.example.com".

It is worth noting that sometimes we want to present different DNS information to clients in different locations. On a single host, you can override the information from DNS by adding a record in the hosts file (/etc/hosts on Linux/Unix/MacOS, C:\Windows\sytem32\drivers\etc\hosts on MS-Windows). To interfere with DNS for lots of machines (within a network you control) then dnsmasq (replaces Bind) is useful.